# GPS: Not receiving any valid output from ATGM336H

Tags: arduino-pro-mini, gps

I have an Arduino Pro Mini along with a GPS Unit - ATGM336H. Below is the sketch I'm currently using:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include "Ublox.h"
SoftwareSerial GPS(4,5);
Ublox serial_gps;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  GPS.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  while(GPS.available()){
  char c = GPS.read();
  if(serial_gps.encode(c)){
  Serial.println(serial_gps.longitude); 
    }
  }
}
```

I'm able to receive NMEA stream from the GPS Unit and parse (tried TinyGPS++, TinyGPS and Ublox) the stream but the data is not valid nor does it ever change. I've read that this GPS unit can take up to 32 seconds to get a fixed position and deliver valid co-ords but I cannot receive any.

[image: Serial Monitor]

Is there anything obviously wrong with my sketch or hardware setup?

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: remove the `if(serial_gps.encode(c)){ Serial.println(serial_gps.longitude); }` .... instead, use `Serial.println(c);` to see if there is any actual data ...... I think that you are sending individual characters to `gps.encode()`, so you get nothing back

Answer (score -1):

while(GPS.available() > 0) {....

Also is the GPS unit outside?

Comment: I have tested the project both indoors and outdoors. I do receive NMEA streams but they seems to be lacking critical info.
I will include the `>0` and get back to you with a result

Comment: There is no difference between `while(GPS.available())` and `while(GPS.available() > 0)`. 0 is `false` anything else is `true` and `GPS.available()` doesn't return negative values.

Comment: available() returns the number of bytes in the RX buffer, so if you juts use available() zero will be returned and the sub will run and return zeros which is what his output looks like. If you use available() > 0 then only when 1 or more bytes exist then the sub will run.

Comment: If `available()` returns zero then the `while` loop will not run, since zero is `false`.